# A/B tesing, cookie choose format

Tags: cookies, ab-testing

when implement the online A/B testing campaign,  what does the cookie_id group mean?

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| A (Group,min,max)  B (Group, min, max)  |
+-----------------------------------------+
| A (10,0,7)         B(10,8,9)            |
| A (8,0,0)          B(8,1,1)             |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Are you using a particular A/B testing tool?  It'd help if you could provide us with more context into what you're doing.